# If cathode rays travel from the cathode to the anode how do they make zinc sulphide glow?

Tags: particle-physics

So I basically learned about cathode rays today, and I had a lot of questions in mind.

So my textbook says cathode rays travel from the cathode to the anode.

So it further says that to observe these rays scientists perforated the anode and coated the other side with zinc sulphide which then glowed as cathode rays hit them because of their property that they make fluroscent stuff glow.

So my question is how do these cathode rays cross the anode and go hit the tube surface without any potential attracting it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do these cathode rays cross the anode?

Either through the perforations or past the edges. Some won't make it through, but the ones that do will be observed.

The electric field is strongest in the region between the anode and cathode.  While some of the field does leak out to the sides and behind them, it is significantly smaller.  The electrons are moving a high speed as they pass the anode and the much lower field there cannot stop them before they reach the zinc sulfide target.

Comment: Particularly if the anode is actually held at ground potential...